MDI Child with no caption - Delphi 12.1 behaviour has changed
I have an MDI project. The MDI Child form does not have a caption. I remove it using this code:
procedure CreateParams(var Params : TCreateParams) ; override ;
 
procedure TFormChart.CreateParams(var Params : TCreateParams) ;
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params) ;
  Params.Style := (Params.Style) and (not ws_Caption) ;
end ;

In the MDI Child form, I have a label. I click on the label and drag to move the form, and double click on the label to maximize the form. I use the following code to achieve this:
procedure WMHitTest(VAR Msg: TWMNcHitTest); Message WM_NCHITTEST;

procedure TFormChart.WMHitTest(var Msg: TWMNcHitTest);
begin
  Inherited;

  //ScripNameRect contains the coords of the label which acts as the form caption
  if PtInRect(ScripNameRect,ScreenToClient(Point(Msg.XPos,Msg.YPos))) then
  begin
    Msg.Result := HTCAPTION ;
  end;
end;

This has been working from Delphi 5 (yr 2000) until Delphi 11.3. I installed Delphi 12.1 and the above code has stopped working. CreateParams() is getting called and the form is drawn without a caption. But WMHitTest is NOT getting called.
Delphi 12.1 has changed MDI after 25+ years.

"Delphi 12.1 has changed MDI after 25+ years." - That is an understatement. It was a major overhaul, and I would not be surprised if a lot of old MDI code breaks because of it. In any case, rather than using WM_HITTEST, have you tried the WM_SYSCOMMAND(SC_DRAGMOVE) trick instead?

The MDI changes and its intentions are mentioned here: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/What%27s_New#MDI_Reworked_for_HighDPI_and_Styles

Thanks Remy. sc-dragmove worked. There are other mdi problems. will add a new question.
